# Optimizing a function to place circle in position which does not overlap other circles

Tags: algorithm

I have an algorithm which places circles in an xy-plane. For the record I am programming this in PHP at the moment, but this question is mainly in regards to a larger algorithm.

So here is the basic algorithmic code:

```
function create_circles($n) {
  for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
    $x = rand_x();
    $y = rand_y();
    $coord = array($x, $y);
    $radius = rand_radius();
    if ($i !== 0) {
      for ($m = 0; $m < $i; $m++) {
        $distance = distance($coord, $position[$m]);
        if ($radius + $radii[$m] > $distance) {
          //REPEAT FUNCTION AGAIN
        } else {
          continue;
        }
      }
    }
    //If function completes correctly
    $radii[$i] = $radius;
    $position[$i] = $coord;
  }
}
```

This is a simplified code and I did not include any variable declarations or auxiliary functions.  I hope this is enough info.

As it stands, this function works, but it takes an hours to place 100 circles.  I am looking for a way to streamline this function and cut down on execution time.

**EDIT**

OK, to address the comment and the answer.  First thank you very much.  Second I will provide a little more information.

The environment dimensions are infinite HOWEVER and this is important, the random position generator favors positions closer to the origin (0, 0).  Therefore the final result should include that the majority of the circles are located in the center.  This distribution is represented by 1/x.

The circles are also plotted along a spiral path (ie. y=atsint, x=atcos)  with some random offset included.

I don't need complete randomness, but just a simulation of randomness if that would improve performance, ie. I would consider narrowing random min, max in favor increasing speed.

Comment: You could also adapt your question to include some keyword like spatial or coverage, to attract the right crowd. Also, since this is a mostly theoretical question, I would remove the php tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this strategy:

1. Create the random coordinates first and assume a zero radius for each for them
2. Calculate for each the distance to the closest other point in the set. This is an upper limit to what radius can be set for a given circle: *max_radius*
3. Choose the circle that has the highest *max_radius* among the circles that did not get a definitive radius in this algorithm
4. Generate a random radius for it which should stay below its *max_radius*
5. Check the distances that all other points have to this new circle, and reduce their *max_radius* if needed.
6. Repeat from step 3 until there are no more circles without radius.

This process runs in *O(n²)*. It could be further optimised, but I found for 100 circles the result is almost immediate:

```
<?php
function rand_x() {
    // use your own code and random distribution here. This is just a mock.
    return rand(10, 490); 
}
function rand_y() {
    // use your own code and random distribution here. This is just a mock.
    return rand(10, 290);
}
function rand_radius($max) {
    // Use your own code and random distribution here. This is just a mock.
    // However: it should not generate a number higher than the parameter value!
    return rand(0, min($max, 50));
}
function distance($a, $b) {
    return sqrt(pow(($a[0]-$b[0]),2) + pow(($a[1]-$b[1]),2));
}

function create_circles($n) {
    $position = array();
    // Generate all circles with radius 0
    for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
        $circles[] = array(
            "id" => $i,
            "position" => array(rand_x(), rand_y()),
            "radius" => 0,
            "max_radius" => 1e100 // "infinity"
        );
    }
    function &adjustRadiiToCircle(&$ref_circle, &$circles) {
        $selected_circle = null;
        foreach ($circles as &$circle) {
            if ($circle['radius'] == 0 and $ref_circle['id'] !== $circle['id']) { // not yet assigned a radius
                $distance = distance($circle['position'], $ref_circle['position']);
                $circle['max_radius'] = min($circle['max_radius'], $distance - $ref_circle['radius']);
                if ($selected_circle == null or $circle['max_radius'] > $selected_circle['max_radius']) {
                    $selected_circle = &$circle;
                }
            }
        }
        return $selected_circle;
    }
    // Calculate maxium radius that each circle can have
    // and remember the one with the highest value for that
    $selected_circle = null;
    foreach ($circles as $circle) {
        // Set or adapt max_distance for all circles in relation to this circle
        $selected_circle = &adjustRadiiToCircle($circle, $circles);
        // NB: we ignore the return value, except for last iteration
    }

    // Choose n times a circle to give it a random radius
    foreach ($circles as $ignore){
        // Get a random radius for the selected circle.
        // The rand_radius function gets an argument, so it can make sure not to generate
        // anything greater than that.      
        $selected_circle['radius'] = rand_radius($selected_circle['max_radius']);
        $selected_circle = &adjustRadiiToCircle($selected_circle, $circles);
    };
    return $circles;
}   

$circles = create_circles(100);

?>
<canvas width="500" height="300" style="border: 1px solid"></canvas>
<script>
var circles = <?=json_encode($circles)?>;
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

for (var circle of circles) {
    console.log(circle.position[0],circle.position[1],circle.radius);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(circle.position[0],circle.position[1], circle.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'yellow';
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    ctx.stroke();
}
</script>
```

I added some JavaScript in that PHP, which draws the circles on a canvas. Here is an example of the script generated, so to show the result:

```js
var circles = [{"id":0,"position":[318,82],"radius":3,"max_radius":51.6623654124},{"id":1,"position":[397,52],"radius":10,"max_radius":15.8113883008},{"id":2,"position":[150,113],"radius":21,"max_radius":27.7308492477},{"id":3,"position":[296,194],"radius":1,"max_radius":15.0512483795},{"id":4,"position":[251,194],"radius":3,"max_radius":20.8086520467},{"id":5,"position":[97,253],"radius":3,"max_radius":3.49285568454},{"id":6,"position":[484,16],"radius":25,"max_radius":73},{"id":7,"position":[76,141],"radius":16,"max_radius":16.1245154966},{"id":8,"position":[133,195],"radius":2,"max_radius":6.39607805437},{"id":9,"position":[361,287],"radius":1,"max_radius":34.8281495345},{"id":10,"position":[57,282],"radius":19,"max_radius":41.4366987102},{"id":11,"position":[252,270],"radius":2,"max_radius":12.0830459736},{"id":12,"position":[67,73],"radius":10,"max_radius":19.2353840617},{"id":13,"position":[356,117],"radius":5,"max_radius":10.9317121995},{"id":14,"position":[152,238],"radius":11,"max_radius":21.3775583264},{"id":15,"position":[394,273],"radius":14,"max_radius":17.0293863659},{"id":16,"position":[43,180],"radius":2,"max_radius":12.0830459736},{"id":17,"position":[53,111],"radius":14,"max_radius":19.4164878389},{"id":18,"position":[478,202],"radius":18,"max_radius":18.3847763109},{"id":19,"position":[18,143],"radius":10,"max_radius":11.0453610172},{"id":20,"position":[174,66],"radius":3,"max_radius":3.60555127546},{"id":21,"position":[175,101],"radius":2,"max_radius":6.73084924772},{"id":22,"position":[117,145],"radius":14,"max_radius":19.2353840617},{"id":23,"position":[391,144],"radius":11,"max_radius":12.8617393793},{"id":24,"position":[78,157],"radius":0,"max_radius":0.124515496597},{"id":25,"position":[233,77],"radius":7,"max_radius":8.94427191},{"id":26,"position":[247,281],"radius":1,"max_radius":3.04536101719},{"id":27,"position":[90,182],"radius":22,"max_radius":23.3452350599},{"id":28,"position":[102,259],"radius":1,"max_radius":7.46424919657},{"id":29,"position":[489,147],"radius":2,"max_radius":15.2626765016},{"id":30,"position":[346,234],"radius":4,"max_radius":15.5600808897},{"id":31,"position":[214,225],"radius":6,"max_radius":27.6586333719},{"id":32,"position":[203,154],"radius":0,"max_radius":1.76305461424},{"id":33,"position":[72,115],"radius":1,"max_radius":5.41648783895},{"id":34,"position":[106,51],"radius":2,"max_radius":6.80441152621},{"id":35,"position":[419,162],"radius":9,"max_radius":12.0415945788},{"id":36,"position":[177,64],"radius":0,"max_radius":0.605551275464},{"id":37,"position":[428,170],"radius":3,"max_radius":3.04159457879},{"id":38,"position":[335,196],"radius":24,"max_radius":33.5261092285},{"id":39,"position":[34,239],"radius":10,"max_radius":17},{"id":40,"position":[100,154],"radius":1,"max_radius":5.23538406167},{"id":41,"position":[38,201],"radius":1,"max_radius":6.76972864801},{"id":42,"position":[241,73],"radius":0,"max_radius":1.94427191},{"id":43,"position":[153,199],"radius":14,"max_radius":20.3960780544},{"id":44,"position":[64,92],"radius":4,"max_radius":7.9544984001},{"id":45,"position":[88,238],"radius":14,"max_radius":17.4928556845},{"id":46,"position":[54,175],"radius":7,"max_radius":10.0830459736},{"id":47,"position":[289,148],"radius":7,"max_radius":39.9624824054},{"id":48,"position":[60,210],"radius":17,"max_radius":23.769728648},{"id":49,"position":[428,95],"radius":2,"max_radius":13.0208242989},{"id":50,"position":[424,213],"radius":10,"max_radius":17.88854382},{"id":51,"position":[418,68],"radius":9,"max_radius":26.4007575649},{"id":52,"position":[451,211],"radius":8,"max_radius":23.6008474424},{"id":53,"position":[385,176],"radius":6,"max_radius":29.8516480713},{"id":54,"position":[193,243],"radius":17,"max_radius":21.6586333719},{"id":55,"position":[208,170],"radius":15,"max_radius":16.7630546142},{"id":56,"position":[176,142],"radius":4,"max_radius":5.09901951359},{"id":57,"position":[131,242],"radius":1,"max_radius":10.3775583264},{"id":58,"position":[345,164],"radius":6,"max_radius":9.52610922848},{"id":59,"position":[251,238],"radius":4,"max_radius":9.20459156783},{"id":60,"position":[416,197],"radius":5,"max_radius":7.88854382},{"id":61,"position":[310,273],"radius":5,"max_radius":6.89173349139},{"id":62,"position":[132,68],"radius":11,"max_radius":23.7234787586},{"id":63,"position":[217,110],"radius":20,"max_radius":22.5610283454},{"id":64,"position":[452,94],"radius":11,"max_radius":22.3882694814},{"id":65,"position":[329,229],"radius":1,"max_radius":9.5410196625},{"id":66,"position":[21,154],"radius":0,"max_radius":1.40175425099},{"id":67,"position":[486,275],"radius":17,"max_radius":43.1856457634},{"id":68,"position":[121,226],"radius":2,"max_radius":18.8679622641},{"id":69,"position":[268,182],"radius":5,"max_radius":17.8086520467},{"id":70,"position":[300,276],"radius":3,"max_radius":5.44009029334},{"id":71,"position":[98,276],"radius":10,"max_radius":17.4642491966},{"id":72,"position":[212,132],"radius":1,"max_radius":2.56102834536},{"id":73,"position":[384,43],"radius":1,"max_radius":5.81138830084},{"id":74,"position":[484,89],"radius":10,"max_radius":32.3882694814},{"id":75,"position":[457,243],"radius":15,"max_radius":22.2036033112},{"id":76,"position":[465,166],"radius":4,"max_radius":21.0950231097},{"id":77,"position":[379,66],"radius":1,"max_radius":2},{"id":78,"position":[377,66],"radius":0,"max_radius":1},{"id":79,"position":[279,201],"radius":8,"max_radius":12.4499705536},{"id":80,"position":[251,73],"radius":1,"max_radius":3.40175425099},{"id":81,"position":[232,158],"radius":8,"max_radius":11.83281573},{"id":82,"position":[365,137],"radius":11,"max_radius":12.319604517},{"id":83,"position":[236,282],"radius":8,"max_radius":11.0453610172},{"id":84,"position":[118,12],"radius":34,"max_radius":40.8044115262},{"id":85,"position":[290,242],"radius":30,"max_radius":35.4400902933},{"id":86,"position":[470,225],"radius":1,"max_radius":6.35159132377},{"id":87,"position":[384,116],"radius":16,"max_radius":28.0178514522},{"id":88,"position":[107,166],"radius":0,"max_radius":1.34523505986},{"id":89,"position":[248,62],"radius":8,"max_radius":11.401754251},{"id":90,"position":[413,130],"radius":1,"max_radius":16.2024843762},{"id":91,"position":[19,231],"radius":5,"max_radius":7},{"id":92,"position":[482,231],"radius":5,"max_radius":11.2745623366},{"id":93,"position":[485,219],"radius":0,"max_radius":0.38477631085},{"id":94,"position":[486,164],"radius":2,"max_radius":17.0950231097},{"id":95,"position":[216,148],"radius":4,"max_radius":8.40939982144},{"id":96,"position":[383,260],"radius":3,"max_radius":3.02938636593},{"id":97,"position":[19,154],"radius":0,"max_radius":1.04536101719},{"id":98,"position":[175,147],"radius":0,"max_radius":1.09901951359},{"id":99,"position":[242,170],"radius":1,"max_radius":15.6204993518}];
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

for (var circle of circles) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(circle.position[0],circle.position[1], circle.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'yellow';
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

```html
<canvas width="500" height="300" style="border: 1px solid"></canvas>
```

Comment: Beautiful, works perfectly and it only took 8 seconds for 1000 iterations on my machine.  Thank you very much. I will attempt to improve it to further optimize it.

Comment: You're welcome. ;-) Hint: optimisation can be done by storing an extra key for each circle ("neighbors"), which is an array of circles that have the potential of touching this circle (they don't have to, but they could without overlapping other points). These "neighbors" are the only ones to look at in step 5. They are the "other points".

Answer (score 1):

(I welcome anyone to edit my answer if you have better information ... and there will be people who do)

#### Thoughts

The question is not that clear in regards to how many randomness you need. Right now you're dropping a circle with random radius and random position on a field of random circles. Depending on the parameters this can take a very very long time. Imagine a 1x1 square and a maximum radius of 0.5. If the first circle lands right in the middle and has a radius close to the middle almost every coordinate after that has to be very close to 0 or 1 and have a radius very close to 0. Depending on how much space is left, the chances of a circle not intersecting any other circle are apparently very slim at some point.

Now the question with randomness appears. How much randomness do you need? Is it okay to limit the selection of radii? For example if you have a maxium radius of `X/2` in a square box, the average radius being tested will be `X/4`. This kind of circle will only fit 4 times in the box (with perfect positioning). After those four positions are exhausted, half of your tests will already fail just because circles with the average radius technically can't fit anywhere. And this is the very conservative approach.

Circles have a very nasty and a very nice property. The nasty one is, they are hard to approximate. The nice one is, overlap is easy to determine.

#### Naive optimization: grid

You could probably make a grid with a sensible width. Then for each cell have a list of circles that overlap that cell, and also note, if the cell is already filled. Depending on the size of the grid cells and the average size of the circle (the cell size should be smaller) there will be either many or few cells that are completely overlapped (many is better -> narrower grid). Now if you roll for a coordinate you can already abort, when there's no chance a circle can fit anywhere, without rolling a random radius. Also by looking at the surrounding cells you can figure out, what the maximum radius can possibly be. You could store that radius for each cell as well. These thoughts ultimately lead to ...

#### General optimization: spatial index structure

There are some index structures that will answer the question of coverage and can store circles (among other things). Keyword spatial index / spatial database. You shouldn't implement those if you can help it. The main idea is, that you have some algorithm that splits your space into smaller and smaller parts to reduce the number of comparisons to be done and can answer the question of coverage very fast. To be honest, there are quite a lot of those indexes and it's not my field of expertise, so you might do some research on which index is probably the best in your use case.

#### Changing the problem?

If you are allowed to change how the circles are produced, you could first find a position, that not already overlaps another circle, then determine the maximum radius a circle at that position could have, then roll a random radius with that maximum. (this would be my prefered approach, if changing the problem is allowed. It *probably* could be shown, that this produces almost similar results to the other method ... but I'm not certain and I could be wrong)

Comment: Thank you, your last solution seems like it'll work so I will try that.